# Assigning enum value to integer crashes program

Tags: c++, casting, enums, crash

I have created an enum with these values:

```
enum Car_Manufacturer
{
   AUDI     = 1,
   CHRYSLER = 2,
   FORD     = 3,
   HONDA    = 4,
   LEXUS    = 5,
   NISSAN   = 6,
   MERCEDES = 7,
   PORSCHE  = 8,
   VOLVO    = 9

};
```

I have the user enter a character which corresponds to the model of car they want to view. I need the character the user entered to become a integer which corresponds to the values in the enum so that I can easily search through an array to find a car of the correct make. The function I created looks like this:

```
int set_car_make_ch( char input )
{  
   int manufacturer = 0;
   if( input == 'A' )
   {
      manufacturer = AUDI;   
   }
   else if( input == 'C' )
   {
     manufacturer = CHRYSLER;
   }
   else if( input == 'F' )
   {   
      manufacturer = (int)FORD;
   }
   else if( input == 'H' )
   {
     manufacturer = HONDA;
   }
   else if( input == 'L' )
   {
     manufacturer = LEXUS;
   }
   else if( input == 'M' )
   {
     manufacturer = MERCEDES;
   }
   else if( input == 'N' )
   {
     manufacturer = NISSAN;
   }
   else if( input == 'P' )
   {
     manufacturer = PORSCHE;
   }
   else if( input == 'V' )
   {
     manufacturer = VOLVO;
   }
   else
   {
      cout<<"Invalid Car Manufacturer, please edit the input file."<<endl;
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
   }
   return manufacturer;
}
```

The program freezes and crashes when an enum value attempts to be assigned to an integer. I am using the G++ compiler. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly does it crash?

Comment: How do you call that function?

Comment: Please, use a lookup table for converting `enum` to text or vice versa.  The `if-else-if` ladders are very annoying to read.

Comment: You could use GDB since you are using G++.  Learn it now, so you can better debug later programs.

Comment: @DGomez I called the function like this:

Comment: car_make = set_car_make_ch( car_make_ch );

Comment: Works fine for me. http://ideone.com/73JKEy.

Comment: I think it crashes when you read stdin...

Comment: The variables are declared at:
int car_make = 0;
char decision_char, car_make_ch;
@ThomasMatthews I am not sure how to implement those, but I consider it for future applications.

Comment: Also, don't use `int` for instances of `enum` types; use the `enum` type.

Comment: @user1505399 You say it crashes. But you don't provide debug info. And you don't provide enough code for us to reproduce your problem. You have to provide a simple working example that reproduces your problem. For 2 very good reasons : it will help people help you, and it will help you identify the core of your problem, and that's 50% of the debugging done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use a lookup table or a `switch` statement rather than the `if-else-if` ladder.

### Lookup Table

```
struct Car_Text_Enum_Entry
{
  const char * name;
  Car_Manufacturer enum_value;
};

const static Car_Text_Enum_Entry enum_conversion[] =
{
  {"AUDI", AUDI},
  {"BMW",  BMW},
  {"DODGE", DODGE},
  //...
};
const unsigned int number_of_conversions = 
  sizeof(enum_conversion) / sizeof(enum_conversion[0]);

Car_Manufacturer Car_Text_To_Enum(char car_mfg_letter)
{
  Car_Manufacturer manufacturer = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_of_conversions; ++i)
  {
    if (enum_conversion[i].name[0] == car_mfg_letter)
    {
      manufacturer = enum_conversion[i].enum_value;
      break;
    }
  }
  return manufacturer;
}
```

The lookup table is a lot *tighter* code and to added or remove manufacturers only requires changing the table, not the code.

### Switch Statement

The switch statement approach will work for letters, but not for strings.  For strings, use a lookup table.

```
Car_Manufacturer Car_Mfg_Letter_To_Enum(char car_mfg_letter)
{
  Car_Manufacturer manufacturer;
  switch (car_mfg_letter)
  {
    case 'A' : manufacturer = AUDI; break;
    case 'B' : manufacturer = BMW; break;
    case 'D' : manufacturer = DODGE; break;
    case 'H' : manufacturer = HONDA; break;
    // ...
  }
  return manufacturer;
}
```

The `switch` statement approach is still more readable and easier to maintain than the `if-else-if` ladder.  However, it will not work with strings (a.k.a. multiple letters).

### Maps

However, if you have learned about `std::map`, you can use it also:

```
typedef std::map<char, Car_Manufacturer> Car_Mfg_Container;
Car_Mfg_Container car_mfg_association;
// Initialization:
car_mfg_association['A'] = AUDI;
car_mfg_association['B'] = BMW;
//...

Car_Manufacturer Car_Mfg_Letter_To_Enum(char car_mfg_letter)
{
  return car_mfg_association[car_mfg_letter];
}
```

Unlike the static, constant, lookup table, the `std::map` must be initialized during runtime.

So, please, don't use `if-else-if` ladders for things that can be looked up in a table.

Also, with enumerations, you only need to assign a value to the first item.

Comment: This is very informative, but doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: I know.  I was hoping that by using another technique, the OP's issue would go away. :-)

Comment: Everytime you don't use a std container and re-invent the wheel a kitten dies.

Comment: Sometimes, cats must die.  In the embedded systems world, a lookup table can be stored in ROM with direct access and not require any dynamic memory accesses.  And other times, kittens are consumed by predatory animals such as coyotes.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - STL containers don't require dynamic memory access. Why can't you use them in embedded systems - the STL was designed to work in such environments.

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained what (if any...) error message you are getting or how you are using this function, but it's generally not a good idea to rely implicit or C style casting from `enum` to `int` when you have better tools available in C++:

Try this: Declare your variable as type `Car_Manufacturer`:

```
Car_Manufacturer manufacturer{};
```

If for some reason you must use `int` try this:

```
manufacturer = static_cast < int >(FORD);
```

If there is something else wrong, instead of just crashing because you're doing an explicit, C style cast, you should get a reasonable error message from `static_cast`.

The best way to avoid such issues entirely is to use [**C11's Scoped enumerations**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), which are strongly typed and cannot simply be cast as integers.

*(As an aside, as @ThomasMatthews has explained, use `switch`, not `if/else if` when you have an `enum`, `char` or `int`.)*